# Compound Random Variable

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, gamma-distribution

May I ask a question regarding compound random variables, in which I want to obtain the distribution of $T$?
$T=\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_i$, where $t_i$ are i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$, and $N$ is geometric distributed random variable, i.e. $P(N = k) = (1 - p)^kp$ .
What I have tried now, is as follow

since $\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i $ follows gamma distribution with parameter $n, \lambda$

$P(T = t) = P(\sum_{i=1}^N t_i = t) = 
\sum_{i = 1}^\infty P(\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i = t) P(N = n)$

after that, when I try to simplify the formula using gamma distribution, I have nowhere to go, anyone can help me?

Comment: Essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052465/compound-geometric-distribution and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469529/sum-of-n-n-geo-exponentially-distributed-random-variables-is-exponentially-di